# How to clear the cached file path in flutter?

Tags: flutter, nullpointerexception, flutter-downloader

I have downloaded pdf file via my flutter app then deleted that file, and I tried to download the same file with same name keep failing.

Here I am using the Flutterdownloader.enqueue to download the file.

When. re-download I am getting below mentioned error:

D/DownloadWorker(12373): Update notification: {notificationId: 8, title: GOA-1924573-2180476 (2).pdf, status: FAILED, progress: -1}

W/System.err(12373): java.lang.NullPointerException